# Logging queries with sqlalchemy 0.6

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, turbogears, turbogears2

With turbogears 2.1 and sqlalchemy 0.7 the queries from console were logged out to stdout. However I needed to downgred to 0.6 and they no longer appear. Documentation of logging seems to be identical and I couldn't find anything in changelog. How to log in sqlalchemy 0.6?

**EDIT** The `DBSession.bind.echo` is set to `False`. If I set it to `True` it works. Any idea how to set it correctly (I'v modified `model/__init__.py` setting `engine.echo = True`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration file should have the specified options. Look for those inside the `development.ini`

```
sqlalchemy.echo = true
sqlalchemy.echo_pool = true
```

Comment: For some reasons it is writted `#echo shouldn't be used together with the logging module.` and the logging module does not work with 0.6.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about TurboGears, but you need to ensure that the engine's `echo` setting is set to `True`, e.g.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
```

By default, the `echo` setting is `False`, so queries aren't logged to stdout. It's possible that TG configures the two SA versions differently.